# NHibernate: Mapping members that are instances of unmapped classes

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I am working on a program that uses NHibernate and I have the following problem:
Some of my classes have members which are instances of classes that basically just define some handlers.

For example

```
public class Foo
{
    virtual public ResultHandler handler {get; set;}
    virtual void Bar()
    {
       ...
       handler.HandleResult(...);
    }
}

public abstract class ResultHandler
{
    abstract public void HandleResult(...);
}

public class ResultPrint : ResultHandler
{
    override public void HandleResult(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ResultExport : ResultHandler
{
    override public void HandleResult(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now ResultPrint and ResultExport don't have any members, so they don't have to be mapped to tables in the database, but when I store / retrieve an instance of Foo, I want to somehow store & load the member "handler".

I could store the class name in a string and use reflection to load it (but that would be unstable in case of renaming of classes and it would waste space in the database). It would be sufficient to store a single byte - but how do I tell NHibernate to do that?

The best I can come up with is to map a virtual member like

```
virtual public byte HandlerClass
{
    get
    {
        if(handler == null)
            return 0;
        switch(handler.GetType())
        {
            case typeof(ResultPrint):
                return 1;
            ... 
        }
    }
    set
    {
        switch(value)
        {
            case 0:
                handler = null;
                break;
            case 1:
                handler = new ResultPrint();
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

but that is absurdly complicated for something that should be a common use case...
There has to be a "clean" way to make NHibernate to that on its own.
Can anyone help me?

Kind regards

AlgoMan

EDIT: I am using XML-based mapping btw.

Answer (score 1):

I presume, while concrete classes ResultPrint and ResultExport don´t any instance members, the abstract class ResultHandler has some members to be saved in database.

You can map ResultHandler, ResultPrint and ResultExport in one table with a discriminator column.

Ex:

```
<class name="ResultHandler" abstract="true" table="ResultHandlers">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/> <!-- WHATEVER IS YOUR IDENTITY HERE! -->
    </id>
    <discriminator column="type" not-null="true" type="System.String"/>

    <subclass name="ResultPrint" discriminator-value="print">
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="ResultExport" discriminator-value="export">
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Besides its normal columns, ResultHandlers table must have an additional column to map subclasses which in the mapping example above is the "type" column.

When the subclass is ResultPrint this column will be automatically filled as "print" or "export" for ResultExport when one of the objects from those classes are saved in database for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I meant. None of the ResultHandler classes should be mapped to the database. The "handler" member of Foo should be assigned through a column in the table of  class Foo...

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, your `ResultHandler` objects do not need to be persisted.
And in fact, this does not really seem like a NH problem.

Persisting your Foo state by just persisting some data allowing to rebuild a correct ResultHandler seems a correct approach to me.

The only thing is that the logic of building a `ResultHandler` from a byte should not be handled by `Foo`. It should belong to a dedicated class, and be reusable (maybe you can use some dependency injection mecanism if you feel like it)

This would lead to something like :

```
private byte _handlerClass;
virtual public byte HandlerClass{
               get{return _handlerClass; }
               set{_handlerClass = value; _handler =null;}
             }

private ResultHandler _handler;   
public virtual ResultHandler Handler
{
    get{
       return _handler ?? (_handler = HandlerServiceLocator.GetHandler(HandlerClass));
    }
}
```

And then, the dedicated class from building a `ResultHandler` from a byte :

```
public class HandlerServiceLocator
{

  public static ResultHandler GetHandler(byte value)
  {
        switch(value)
        {
            case 0:
                return null;
            case 1:
                return  new ResultPrint();
            ...
        }
        return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that is (logically) about the same solution I came up with... There has to be a cleaner way... I mean NHibernate must have some mechanism to automate that, because I don't think that having stateless members of non-elementary type in a mapped class is such an unusual case...

Comment: @Algoman yes, as I pointed out, this seems a correct approach. Having this at NH level would be with IUserType see http://lukaszbaran.com/blog/?p=176 (especially NullSafeGet and NullSafeSet) Another similar approach to above might be using implicit conversion operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx